# togglePages function returning null

Tags: flutter, function, dart, toggle

I'm going to list the implementations of the function in the TogglePage class across all the files it's in. Please take a look:

toggle_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:teens_next/app/authentication/authentication.dart';

class TogglePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TogglePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TogglePage> createState() => _TogglePageState();
}

class _TogglePageState extends State<TogglePage> {
  // show login page at start
  bool showLoginPage = true;

  //toggle between login and register pages
  void togglePages() {
    setState(() {
      showLoginPage = !showLoginPage;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (showLoginPage) {
      return SigninPage(
        onTap: togglePages,
      );
    } else {
      return SignupPage(
        onTap: togglePages,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is where the main function is located, operating using a boolean to determine whether or not the sign in or sign up page should be displayed on the screen. Speaking of logging in, here are the implementations of the function in the signin and sign up.dart files, respectively:

```
// rest of file can be ignored

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Not a member?',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 4),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: widget.onTap,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Register now',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
```

```
// rest of file can be ignored

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Already a member?',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 4),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: widget.onTap,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Sign in now',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
```

And finally, the last implementation lies within the splash_page.dart file. It's doesn't explicitly use the function but when the splash page redirects to the sign in page, the parameter onTap is passed in to indicate that an event should occur upon pressing the toggle page buttons (listed above):

```
// rest of file can be ignored


          StartButton(

            onPressed: () {

              Navigator.push(

                  context,

                  CupertinoPageRoute(

                      builder: (context) => SigninPage(

                            onTap: () {},

                          )));

            },

          ),
```

Upon clicking the button to toggle pages, no result is returned when I debug the code in edge console. The screen remains the same and doesn't appear to have any errors. What exactly am I doing wrong? I can provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In splash screen in the StartButton you are sending blank onTap to the Signin screen.
Thats why onToggle doing nothing.

Push TogglePage intead of Signin page from Splash

Comment: Alright I'll give it a go (most likely it should work).

Comment: did it work the way you wanted?

Comment: Oh yeah it did. Tysm for the help!